Custom Hadamard-style product of two matrices in python
I have two numpy matrices A and B (of size m x n, m<>n, m=number of rows, n=number of columns). Both are digital matrices, consisting solely of entries 0 or 1.
I want to calculate a matrix product C from these two matrices that obeys the following rules in terms of A(row, column):
If A(i,j) = 1 and B(i,j)=1, C(i,j)=1.
If A(i,j) = 1 and B(i,j)=0, C(i,j)=-q.
If A(i,j) = 0, C(i,j) = 0, regardless of the value of B(i,j).

where q satisfies the equation p-(n-p)*q=0 where p is the number of 1s in B(i,:).
I could implement this with a couple of for loops, but I am tempted to ask if there is one of those single line pythonic ways of implementing this logic.

How sparse are A and B? If highly sparse this calls for a different solution

IIUC you can do:
Suppose you have two matrices 5x2:
# A
[[0 1 0 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 0]]

# B
[[0 0 1 1 1]
 [0 0 1 1 0]]

Then:
m, n = A.shape            # 5, 2
p = B.sum(axis=1)         # [3 2]
q = p / (n - p)           # [1.5        0.66666667]

m1 = A & B
m2 = (A & ~B) * -q[:, None]

print(m1 + m2)

Prints:
[[ 0.         -1.5         0.          1.          1.        ]
 [-0.66666667 -0.66666667  1.          1.          0.        ]]


No need for boolean operators. This reduces to one analytic expression:
import numpy as np

# c = a(-q(1 - b) + 1(b))
#   = a(q(b - 1) + b)
# p - (n - p)q = 0
# p/(n - p) = q

m = 20
n = 9
rand = np.random.default_rng(seed=0)
a, b = rand.integers(low=0, high=2, size=(2, m, n))
p = b.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True)
q = p/(n - p)
c = a*(b*(q + 1) - q)

# Tests
assert np.allclose(1, c[(a & b).astype(bool)])
predicate_2 = (a == 1) & (b == 0)
assert np.allclose(
    np.broadcast_to(-q, c.shape)[predicate_2],
    c[predicate_2],
)
assert np.allclose(0, c[a == 0])

